# java -version returning an error but bash profile is correct

Tags: java, linux, bash

When I run `java -version` it returns:

```
-bash: java: command not found.
```

when I go to `opt/java/bin/java -version` it returns `1.6` etc as expected.

If I tab what java's are available at the prompt I get:

```
javac javadoc javah javap
```

but not plain old java.

My `~/.bash_profile` reads:

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/
export JAVA_HOME
```

Tried re-installing java, seeing the same result. Am I missing something?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` won't be used to find the `java` executable. If you run `which javac` what does it show? And what's in your path?

Comment: you need to check your PATH, not only JAVA_HOME

Comment: if one day the bash was re-implemented by java, `JAVA_HOME` could be recognized, also the `bin/` .... ^_*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something?

1. Your bash profile is NOT correct.
2. If `/opt/java` is your Java installation directory, then you need `/opt/java/bin` to be on your command search path; i.e. the `PATH` environment variable.